# ProgressBar: indeterminate + show progress (like google play store)

Tags: android

want to use progressbar like google play store.

Firstly it (progressbar) is indeterminate -- it  displayed as a constantly moving loading. And then it shows progress - from 0 to 100

In my case bar shows only indeterminate or progress - depends of xml-config.
Any suggestion?

My progressbar:
here bar shows moving loading for short time period. When downloading starts progressbar is gone by themself.
Without android:indeterminate="true" no indeterminate and bar shows only progress.
Progress I change by  progress.setProgress((int) _self.currentProgress);

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                style="@style/ProgressBarHoloHorizontal"/>
```

Style:

```
<style name="ProgressBarHoloHorizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

Comment: When you set progress to your progressbar the indeterminate state should dissapear, if not just type `progress.setIndeterminate(false);` when you get your first progress.

Comment: Thanks, @zozelfelfo! It's right solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
progress.setIndeterminate(false);
```

to change from indeterminate to a determinate progress bar

Comment: As mentioned before (see @zozelfelfo comment) progress.setIndeterminate(false) should be added in place, when you get first progress